# I get the error UnicodeEncodeError when deleting an instace of the User class in python/django

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode

I am fairly new to python/Django and i came across an error with the Django admin site. I accidentally created a user with a username that includes the leter "ñ". When I try to delete the record from the Django admin site it gives the error:

`Exception Type:UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

The User class is actually a class that inherited from user.

```
class Investor(User):
    cash = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',max_length=500, default='photos/default.jpeg', null=True)
    #imgurl = models.URLField(max_length=500, default='', null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

I have no idea how to resolve this issue and the answers I have found do not point to the built in user class. Since I do not define the email field because it is already build in the User class from django I cannot change it to unicode. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's because of the call to `str()` in `__unicode__`. It's trying to print the instance, has some non-ascii character in it, and that goes wrong. Why doesn't that method just return `self.email`?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That is right, you should post this as an answer. `__unicode__` returning `str` that is horrible.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. Just replaced the str for the _unicode_. Sorry that was a rookie mistake.